# Find closed form of $f(a,b,c)$

Tags: contest-math

Let $$f(a,b,c)=\left|\dfrac{|b-a|}{|ab|}+\dfrac{b+a}{ab}-2c\right|+\dfrac{|b-a|}{|ab|}+\dfrac{b+a}{ab}+\dfrac{2}{c}.$$ Find closed form to $f$.

Comment: And exactly why don't you consider this form 'closed'?

Comment: Could you tell which is the math contest this question originates, if such is the case?

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to say simplify the following expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|x-y|+x+y=2\max\{x,y\}$ then $$f(a,b,c)=\left|\left|\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{b}\right|+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{2}{c}\right|+\left|\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{b}\right|+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{2}{c}=$$$$=|2\max\{1/a,1/b\}-\dfrac{2}{c}|+2\max\{1/a,1/b\}+\dfrac{2}{c}=$$$$=2\max[2\max\{1/a,1/b\};2/c]=4\max[\max\{1/a,1/b\};1/c]=4\max\{1/a,1/b,1/c\}.$$